# Create span element in li with Javascript

Tags: javascript, appendchild

I'm working on a to-do list project and when creating a new `li` I would like it to start with a `span` containing a "X". I wrote the code below, but instead of a `span` I get "[object HTMLSpanElement]". Anybody knows how to fix this? Thank you!

```
var enterItem = document.querySelectorAll("input");
var todoList = document.getElementById("todo-list");

for (var i = 0; i < enterItem.length; i++) {
  enterItem[i].addEventListener("keypress", function(key) {
    if(key.which === 13){

      var newLi = document.createElement("li");
      var span = document.createElement("span");
      var newItem = this.value;

      span.textContent = "X";
      newLi.appendChild(document.createTextNode(span + " " + newItem));
      todoList.appendChild(newLi);
      this.value = "";
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to add an html element in a textNode so it triggers the toString of the element

You need

```js
const todoList = document.getElementById("todo-list");

document.getElementById("inputContainer").addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.type === "text" && e.which === 13) {
    let newLi = document.createElement("li");
    let span = document.createElement("span");
    span.classList.add("remove");
    let newItem = tgt.value;
    span.textContent = "X";
    newLi.appendChild(span)
    newLi.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" " + newItem));
    todoList.appendChild(newLi);
    tgt.value = "";
  }
});

document.getElementById("todo-list").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("remove")) {
    tgt.closest("li").remove();
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="inputContainer">
  <input type="text" />
</div>
<ul id="todo-list"></ul>
```

Comment: Thank you mplungjan, your previous comment actually made me realise what I did wrong. I changed it to this: newLi.appendChild(span);
      newLi.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newItem));
      todoList.appendChild(newLi);